# How to find uptime of a linux process

Tags: linux, process, grep, uptime

How do I find the uptime of a given linux process.

```
ps aux | grep gedit | grep -v grep
```

gives me a whole lot of information which includes the time at which the process was started.
I am specifically looking for switch which returns the uptime of a process in milliseconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 151):

As "uptime" has several meanings, here is a useful command.

```
ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,time,args
```

This command lists all processes with several different time-related columns. It has the following columns:

```
PID COMMAND                          STARTED     ELAPSED     TIME COMMAND
```

`PID` = Process ID
first `COMMAND` = only the command name without options and without arguments
`STARTED` = the absolute time the process was started
`ELAPSED` = elapsed time since the process was started (**wall clock time**), format [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss 
`TIME` = cumulative CPU time, "[dd-]hh:mm:ss" format
second `COMMAND` = again the command, this time with all its provided options and arguments

Comment: Nice. I prefer `etimes` myself - elapsed time in seconds - so it's machine readable

Comment: the question was about stat time in *milliseconds*

Comment: unfortunately, busybox 1.29.3 broke the formatting for etime, so do not rely on it for parsing.

Answer (score 20):

If you have a limited version of `ps` such as is found in `busybox`, you can get the process start time by looking at the timestamp of `/proc/<PID>`.  For example, if the pid you want to look at is 55...

```
# ls -al /proc | grep 55
dr-xr-xr-x    7 root     root             0 May 21 05:53 55
```

... and then compare it with the current date...

```
# date
Thu May 22 03:00:47 EDT 2014
```

Comment: This seems to no longer work on current kernels.

Comment: this works where `ps -ef ...` does not. "4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64"

Comment: can generate the etimes= with proc entries like `etime=$(date -d "$(stat -c %y /proc/${pid} | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2)" +%s); echo "$(date +%s) - ${etime}" | bc -l`

Answer (score 12):

I think you can just run:

```
$ stat /proc/1234
```

1234 being the process id.

example with two processes started at the same hour minute seconds but not the same milliseconds:

```
$ stat /proc/9355
...
Access: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.778791165 +0100
Modify: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.778791165 +0100
Change: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.778791165 +0100
$ stat /proc/9209
...
Access: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.621790420 +0100
Modify: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.621790420 +0100
Change: 2017-11-13 17:46:39.621790420 +0100
```

Comment: In rare cases my `OpenSuse 15.5` shows *future* timestamps for /proc/* -- I wish someone could explain this :(

Answer (score 7):

yes, too old and yet too hard stuff. I tried with the above proposed "stat" method but what if I had "touch"-ed the PID proc dir yesterday? This means my year-old process is shown with yesterday's time stamp. Nah, not what I need :(

In the newer ones, it's simple:

```
ps -o etimes -p <PID>
ELAPSED
339521
```

as simple as that. Time is present in seconds. Do whatever you need it for.
With some older boxes, situation is harder, since there's no etimes. One could rely on:

```
ps -o etime -p <PID>
ELAPSED
76-03:26:15
```

which look a "a bit" weird since it's in dd-hh:mm:ss format. Not suitable for further calculation. I would have preferred it in seconds, hence I used this one:

```
ps -o etime -p <PID> --no-headers | awk -F '(:)|(-)' 'BEGIN{a[4]=1;a[3]=60;a[2]=3600;a[1]=86400;s=0};{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) s=s+a[i]*$i}END{print s}'
339544
```

Comment: This is a really nice way of doing it on the older systems, thanks :)

Comment: do not parse the output of etime because busybox 1.29.3 changed the format. use the stat + /proc method instead

Answer (score 5):

Such a simple thing is not properly answered after 5 years?

I don't think you can accurately get milliseconds. eg. if you see `man procfs` and see `/proc/$$/stat` which has field 22 as startime, which is in "clock ticks", you would have something more precise, but clock ticks aren't going at a perfectly constant rate (relative to 'wall clock time') and will be off... sleeping and certain things (ntpd I guess) offset it. For example on a machine running ntpd, with 8 days uptime and has never slept, `dmesg -T` has the same problem (I think...), and you can see it here:

```
# date; echo h > /proc/sysrq-trigger; dmesg -T | tail -n1 ; date
Fri Mar  3 10:26:17 CET 2017
[Fri Mar  3 10:26:16 2017] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) 
Fri Mar  3 10:26:17 CET 2017
```

Here's seconds:

```
# example pid here is just your shell
pid=$$

# current unix time (seconds since epoch [1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC])
now=$(date +%s)

# process start unix time (also seconds since epoch)
# I'm fairly sure this is the right way to get the start time in a machine readable way (unlike ps)...but could be wrong
start=$(stat -c %Y /proc/"$pid")

# simple subtraction (both are in UTC, so it works)
age=$((now-start))

printf "that process has run for %s seconds\n" "$age"
```

Answer (score 3):

By process name:

```
ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,args | grep MyProcessName | cut -b 1-200
```

Where:

- `MyProcessName` is the process name.
- The `ps` lists all processes.
- The `grep` filters by `MyProcessName` in `args`.
- The `cut` lists the first 200 characters on each line. Useful, as often Java command lines are rather long.

Produces something like this:

```
 10673 java            Tue Aug 25 12:26:30 2020    19:19:25 /opt/apps/java_home/bin/java -Dservice.name=MyProcessName1
 10908 java            Tue Aug 25 12:26:41 2020    19:19:14 /opt/apps/java_home/bin/java -Dservice.name=MyProcessName2
 11062 java            Tue Aug 25 12:26:52 2020    19:19:03 /opt/apps/java_home/bin/java -Dservice.name=MyProcessName3
```

We can see that all of the services started on August 26th at 12:26, and none of them have restarted for any reason.

Comment: `ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,args -q "\`pgrep -f TheCmd\`"` maybe more effective, and avoid grep in list

Answer (score 2):

as **Systemd** got introduced, people who search for this with SystemD distros can use `systemctl status option`. And get the uptime in the output as depicted here:

```
● openkm.service - LSB: Start and stop OpenKM
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/openkm; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-04-20 09:27:13 CAT; 2 weeks 4 days ago
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[root@ip-x-x-x-x ec2-user]# ps -p `pidof java` -o etimes=
 266433
```

`pidof java` => process id for java process

`etimes=` => time in Seconds and '=' is to remove header